# Which file in /usr/local/ shows the version of php on mac

Tags: php, macos

I need to check the version of PHP in my folder /usr/local/php. My system Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.
The command from Terminal PHP -v is fine, but I need to go to that folder and manually search and open the file that shows PHP version. Please, help me on this matter. I am just learning, and I face difficulties with setting up PHP, so I do need to perform that check manually. Which of the folders and which file should I look for in the following list of folders inside the PHP folder:

- bin
- entropy-php.conf
- etc
- include\infor\lib
- libphp5.so
- php.d
- sbin
- share
- var

Thank you very much!

Comment: refer [this](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php) link

Comment: @DNilesh Thank you very much! This link has helped me to find the difference between where apache is looking and where the terminal is taking its info from. I will not create a new post on this issue. Thank you! Still didn't clarify which file contains the exact php version in the directory. I know how to check that from the Terminal, but as I have written in the original question, I need to do it manually, i.e. go to Finder and find the file, open it and see the version.   Sad, there is no option to up vote your helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

just run `php -v`

e.g.

```
# php -v
PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Jul  6 2015 14:28:54)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

If you want to know the version from within your code you can use:

```
<?php 
echo phpversion();

if (phpversion() > 5.6) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I have mentioned in my original message that I know how to find php versions through Terminal and how to do it via localhost. That's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check manually just by looking into a file, one way is checking the php-config file inside the "bin" directory. You can find the version at top lines of the file.

If you're using the default php of your mac it's on /usr/bin/php-config.